# Linux, Rails, Mono C#, No-SQL setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, mono, nosql

Hi I am keen on setting up a Linux box to play around with Rails, No-Sql, Mono C#... and opensource projects!

I am keen on learning Ruby on Rails and don't have a Mac so I think for now the cheapest option is to install a Linux distro on my computer. I am also keen on trying out MongoDB

I am a complete nube to Linux and am wondering if I should install openSuse, Ubuntu, Debian or ? I am also a C# developer so I can install Mono and MonoDevelop. They have packages for these http://monodevelop.com/Download

Anyone have some blog posts, screencasts, books, experience I would **love to hear about it** :)

Cheers
Jake

Comment: I'd suggest Fedora, but I haven't actually used any of those on it in anger.

Comment: You're basically asking "What's the best distro for programming"?  This is just as contentious (and talked to death) as the editor wars.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404520/best-linux-distribution-for-programming-closed for past discussion.  It's also probably more appropriate on superuser.

Comment: Mono and openSuse are always up to date. Since Novel where Miguel works on Mono and Suse is distributed from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: you can still learn Ruby on windows, you can also use Ruby and .NET with [IronRuby](http://ironruby.net/) which is nearly 100% compatible with C Ruby. That's not to stop you from learning linux though as it gives you a different perspective on OS's and will expose you to the power of the command line.

Mono on linux is very complete. The best distribution to use with it would be Open Suse (as it's supported and recommended by Novell who develop Mono).

If you want to go the NoSql route than I would recommend looking at [redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/) a very fast and advanced key-value data store with support for rich data structures, i.e. lists, sets and ordered sets. If you use C#/Mono you can this [redis client](http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/ServiceStackRedis) which has native support for storing complex types and exposes Redis server-side lists and sets as `IList<T>` and `ICollection<T>`'s.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the heads up on the C# redis client that looks cool! Doesn't ruby run pretty slow on windows?

Comment: It used to. Ruby 1.9.x and Iron Ruby are now a lot faster: http://antoniocangiano.com/2009/08/03/performance-of-ironruby-ruby-on-windows/

Answer (score 2):

It probably doesn't matter much which Linux you install on a desktop. The user experience will be determined by Gnome or KDE, not the distro.

The two aspects of linux that have the biggest user-experience impact are the desktop and the package system. Linux has, sadly, two of each.<sup>1.</sup>

There are two desktops: Gnome and KDE. In general, you can choose Gnome or KDE with any distro and you can even install both. (You only run one at a time, though.)  Please realize that except for some configuration details, for the most part the distros redistribute the same set of Unix-model software, so you aren't getting anything wildly different or even as different as XP vs Vista.

Either of the two main package systems can in some ways be used with any distro, but life will be much easier if you stay with the vanilla one for your distro. But since you aren't expecting either one I think it won't matter.

Now, if you went and installed, say, [**NetBSD**](http://www.NetBSD.org/), then you might notice some real differences, although you would *still* have your choice of Gnome or KDE.

---

<sup>1. Technically, there are 10 or 20 window managers that provide interesting lightweight GUI's that are something a bit less than a full-blown desktop GUI, but that's in the advanced class. Also in that class: Unix servers generally run no GUI at all.</sup>

Comment: @DigitalRoss thanks for the info! So I don't really want to start any religious wars here, but which desktop do you prefer out of Gnome and KDE. I will go and do some research but it is always good hearing different opinions :)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Ubuntu or OpenSuse since most of the tutorials, community support and other stuff around Mono is targeted to these distributions.